# How to get default value for form field in symfony2 formbuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I have read that I can set the default value of a field in symfony2 formbuilder by doing this

```
->add('myfield', 'text', array(
  'label' => 'Field',
  'data' => 'Default value'
))
```

Now I want to manipulate the value that would be here by default, in order to know what to set, I need to know what was originally passed, so can I get the default value like

myfield.default_value

so that i can later manipulate it and set the result of my manipulation as the real default value?

Addition:
I tried

```
    ->add('username', 'text', array('label' => 'Användarnamn ', 'data' => 'my_own_defaultvalue'))
```

That didn't work for me (seen it in a bunch of forums though...).

Comment: So you solved this? Best thing would be to edit your question and separate the answer, then accept the answer. In this way when people look for this problem in the future they can find a solved problem

Comment: Agree with @CarlosGranados. Please, if you answered your question - write it as answer and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I realized that probably the easiest way is to just edit the object before I pass it to the formBuilder, like this:

```
public function editUserAction($id)
{   

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('BizTVUserBundle:User')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Container entity.');
    }

      //run some action to modify one of the variables of $entity

    $entity->setUsername($username_stripped); //put my edited variable into the object, now we're ready to pass my new and improved $entity to the formBuilder...

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new editUserType(), $entity);

    return $this->render('BizTVUserBundle:Default:editUser.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```